# How to query azure devops work items for the longest assignment history?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to query work items and find the tickets I was assigned to the longest period of time. You have the "Was Ever @ME" option, but that will also find work items that were merely assigned to me for a short validation. Or is there another place where you can query the historic changes of fields?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure DevOps does not directly support querying work items for the longest assignment history. It is recommended that you check the specific history of the work item based on the query results using the "Was Ever @ME" option.

If you indeed want such a feature, you can submit a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.